Identify users visiting website from Electron or web browser
I have a site I applied nativefier to so it's accessible as an Electron app and I'm trying to determine whether people are visiting through the app or through a standard web browser.
Is there a way I can achieve this from the site homepage using javascript?
I noticed when capturing js errors the url returned for one error from the app was
source: node:electron/js2c/renderer_init
vs the browser
source: https://theapp.thewebsite.com
This was returned after trying to use a js prompt which I subsequently learned is unavailable in Electron.
So far I haven't been able to return node:electron or another differentiating property with js.
The aim is to determine how people are arriving and if it's in Electron they can use the site and if not, redirect them to install the app and access the site from it. TIA

i think you can inject a javascript file containing a line like "window.isElectron = true" and in the main js check if the variable is undefined that means it's running in the browser
